# XML parser suddenly chokes on previous parsed latin characters half way through file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, character-encoding

I have an XML loader class written in c# .net which is supposed to read through XML files, extract relevant bits of data and insert them into a database. So far so ordinary.

However I've got a real head scratcher over its behaviour when encountering one particular file containing latin characters. It loads the bulk of the file and then - quite suddenly - throws an illegal character error on a non-standard character that it's already processed successfully many times.

> DBException: Error bulk copying table to [Table] --->
>   System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line
>   182078, position 47.

This was thrown on the character ñ which has already been processed successfully on lines 506, 999, 1039 and many others. I've checked in a hex editor that they're the same actual character, and they are: U+00F1 ñ c3 b1 LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE.

So I have no idea what's causing it to suddenly become problematic. The problem seems to persist if you copy a fragment that causes the issue into a new file by itself and try and load it from there, and it seems to not matter what the fragment is - so it's unlikely to be an escape character.

Really scratching my head over this one - suggestions much appreciated.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Please post the *bytes* in the file around that character, as well as the declared encoding.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how I can go about discovering what they are? I'm using Hex Editor Neo to get the encoding.

Comment: Use Neo to get to the right area in the file (based on context) and then post the exact bytes... along with the encoding which is probably specified *right at the start of the file*.

Comment: Oh, nice. They bytes are different - the ones that process are decimal 177, the one that chokes is decimal 195. There's no encoding at the start of the file that I can see beyond the xml version 1.0 and namespace declarations - http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 and http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting thoroughly confused now. The values seem to change when it's copied and pasted.

Comment: Okay, if it's not declared in the XML declaration, it will be assumed to be UTF-8 or UTF-16, I believe. Note that if it's UTF-8, a byte of either 177 or 195 isn't a complete character on its own. You should *not* copy and paste the text - it's the *bytes* which are important.

Comment: Ok, this explains a lot. I've had to copy & paste as part of the file preparation and I'm guessing this is what's caused the confusion. I'll try loading the fragments separately and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is alluded to in the comments - this was the result of several copy and paste operations using different text editors, and that can cause the character sets to change.

Always work with the original data where possible!